# how to add scroll view on viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to add Scroll View into ViewController. I have created viewcontroller by code.

```
secondView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"second" bundle:nil];
```

Now i want to add scroll view on view controller. is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yeah it's possible to add scrollview to your viewcontroller.

Follow this,it might help you

```
CGRect rect=CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);

UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 400);
scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
[self.secondview addSubview:scroll];
```

**Edit:**

```
SecondView *secondView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];   
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES]; 

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,600);
    scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(secondView.bounds);
            scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
            scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;              
    [secondView.view addSubview:scroll];        
    [scroll release];
```

Good Luck..

Comment: still not working... also its a navigation based...[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];

Comment: @maulik:Try this..[secondview.view addSubview:scroll];  
  [scroll release];

Comment: @maulik:The above code i have given is works well for me..Let me know if u have any clarifications..

Comment: @Renuga: ya your code is working but page is not scrolling. Only scroll bar appears horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @maulik:There are so many properties for UIScrollview.U want to scroll the page means,you have to give contentsize of scrollview accordingly  Code:scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 800);Height is 800(so,it's scroll horizontally.The same think for width also..

Comment: @maulik:scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES; //scroll horizontally                           scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES; //scroll Vertically

Comment: @Renuga : here is my code : secondView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"second" bundle:nil];
 myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
 [myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(400, 600)];  [secondView.view addSubview:myScrollView];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];

Comment: @renuga : CGSizeMake(secondView.bounds) takes 2 arguments... error occurs " Too few arguments"

Comment: ok..just you specify the width and height values like this: scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400,600);

Comment: see what i did... first i created simple view controller that displays 4 labels. thn i want to scroll them so i have deleted all those labels thn YES i put scroll view on current view thn again i've put 4 labels on scroll view not to view controller.

Comment: secondView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"second" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES]; [secondView.view addSubview:myScrollView];  
 
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600);
 
 myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
 myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400,600);
 myScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
 myScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;

Comment: giv this line:scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;

Comment: @renuga: - in method : (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{}

Answer (score 3):

[viewController.view addSubview:scrollView]

Answer (score 0):

Put following in viewDidLoad of your SecondView class

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

   [super viewDidLoad];
   CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,600);
   UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
   scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(secondView.bounds);
            scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
            scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;              
    [secondView.view addSubview:scroll];        
    [scroll release];
}
```